# Poner líneas a ambos lados de una palabra en html

Tags: html, css

estoy intentando poner dos líneas centradas al lado de una palabra tipo así:

------------------- o ------------------------

O si lo prefieren ver gráficamente, sería algo así (cogido de Twitter):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El caso es que con mi poco conocimiento por el momento, no sé muy bien cómo hacerlo, sé que tengo la etiqueta hr pero no consigo el efecto que quiero. Podrían echarme una mano?

Gracias!!

Comment: Bienvenido, es importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: Gracias, estoy intentando utilizar una etiqueta span en html creando una regla css en la que defina la línea con una relation absoluta: .linea-despues {
    position: absolute;
    top:15px;
    right: 290px;
    width: 150px; 
    height: 1px; 
    background-color: black; 
}.linea-despues {
    position: absolute;
    top:15px;
    right: 290px;
    width: 150px; 
    height: 1px; 
    background-color: black; 
} y luego en mi html poner esa regla en una etiqueta span

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] para agregar más detalles a tu pregunta. La zona de comentarios es solo para aclaraciones.

Comment: Hay varias formas de hacerlo, ayuda saber si hay alguna(s) restricción(es) ¿la palabra es fija? ¿es una sola línea de texto? ¿el ancho y/o la altura son fijos o relativos a qué?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias formas de hacerlo. Puedes intentar utilizar los pseudoelementos `after` y `before` ([más info aquí](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/)) para que crees las líneas desde CSS. Puedes partir de aquí e ir intentando darle el estilo que gustes en este ejemplo, sólo que a veces se puede descuadrar las líneas dependiendo del tamaño de la fuente, pero lo arreglas modificando los valores de `transform`.

```css
h1{
  font-size:3rem;
}

h1::before,
h1::after {
  border-top: .2rem solid black;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 1rem;
  transform: translateY(-1rem);
  width: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Este es un título</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Otra forma podría ser que a la etiqueta `<h1>` le asignes un borde sólido y con `line-height` des el efecto de que quede centrado y finamente a la etiqueta `<span>` le agregas un fondo del mismo color para que el texto cubra el borde y no se vea "tachado".

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000; 
  line-height: 0.1em;
  margin: 10px 0 20px;
  width: 100%;
} 

h1 span { 
  background-color: #fff; 
  padding:0 10px; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><span>El mismo título :D</span></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**Proceso visual de la opción #2:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En la segunda opción,  ¿como haces las rallas? Es que no me ha quedado claro

Comment: @Euricky999 He editado la respuesta y he añadido el proceso visual de la opción #2. Saludos.

Comment: Ahora lo entiendo! Creo que asi, con la respuesta editada se ve mejor la opción #2.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Aunque llego un poco tarde jejeje, lo logré sacar en su día y no volví al foro. Gracias!